# Autocomplete,display search term results?

Tags: php, jquery, autocomplete, autosuggest

A quick question, does anyone know how to make a php script search a database for a record pertaining to the autocomplete search term (if that makes any sense at all).

I guess what I am trying to say is that, when you search for something on Google and then you get the auto-suggestions once you click on a suggestion the results for that suggestion shows straight away...Is there a way of doing this?

Answer (score 0):

Basically you create a form which ajaxes to a file that gives suggestions based on a term via the database (LIKE query possibly).

YOu can use JQueryUI's autocomplete for the client side.

http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/

Answer (score 0):

I think you know how to make an basic auto complete script, right? What you want is showing the results right after the user clicks the auto complete option. Am i right?

What you want to search for is a jQuery autocomplete plugin that has a selection of onComplete action so you can show the results after someone clicks an option.

Like this one for example:
http://sourcery.devbridge.com/components/jquery-autocomplete/

You can use the Selected option to load the results using a ajax request by jQuery.

Hope that puts you in the right direction!

Answer (score 0):

Please try this:

This is HTML page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
$('#search_data').autocomplete({
source:'search_data.php', minLength:2
});
</script>
<title>Search</title>
</head>
<body>
<p><label for="term">Search for: </label> <input type="text" name="search_data" id="search_data"  /></p>
</body>
</html>
```

... and this is search_data.php page:

```
<?php
require 'config.php';
/* prevent direct access to this page */
/* Connect to database and set charset to UTF-8 */

// if the 'term' variable is not sent with the request, exit
if ( !isset($_REQUEST['term']) )
    exit;

// connect to the database server and select the appropriate database for use
$dblink = mysql_connect($hostname, $username, $password) or die( mysql_error() );
mysql_select_db($database);

// query the database table that match 'term'
$rs = mysql_query('select item_name from items where item_name like "'. mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST['term']) .'%" order by item_name asc limit 0,10', $dblink);

// loop through each result returned and format the response for jQuery
$data = array();
if ( $rs && mysql_num_rows($rs) )
{

    while( $row = mysql_fetch_array($rs, MYSQL_ASSOC) )
    {
        $data[] = array(
            'label' => $row['item_name'],
            'value' => $row['item_name']
        );
    }


}

// jQuery wants JSON data
echo json_encode($data);
flush();
?>
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. I tried to run this code and adjust to what the variables names and it did not work.

Answer (score 0):

The best answer for this we have here:

```html
<html>
 <head>
 </head>
 <body>
  <style type="text/css">
   input::-webkit-calender-picker-indicator{
    display: none;
   }
  </style>
  <h1>This form works on ajax</h1>
  <form id="theform">
   <input type="text" name="city" id="city" list="addlist" />
   <input type="submit" value="submit" />
  </form>
  <datalist id="addlist" class="response"></datalist>
  <!-- <div id='response'></div> -->
  
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  
  <script> 
   $('document').ready(function(){
    $('#city').keyup(function(){
     if(!($('#city').val() == ''))
      {
      
     $('#response').html('<b>Loading....</b>');
     
     $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url: 'jqueryfile.php',
      data: $(this).serialize()
     })
     .done(function(data){
      $('.response').html(data);
     })
     .fail(function(){
      alert('data not post');
     });
     return false;
    }else{$('#response').html('<span></span>');}
    });
   })
  </script>
  
 </body>
</html>
```

Here is the php code for this:

```
<?php

    $city = $_POST['city'];
    $con = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'node');
    if(!$con)
        die("Error in connection");
    else
        echo "<br/>connected successfully";
    $sql = "select * from user_details where username like '".$city."%' limit 10";
    if(!$result = mysqli_query($con, $sql))
        die("error in query");
    else
        echo "<br/>data inserted Successfully";
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
            echo "<option id=".$row['user_id'].">".$row['username']."</option>";
        }

    mysqli_close($con);

?>
```